# Python Pandas equivalent of SQL case statement nested in count and sum summary functions

Tags: python, sql, pandas

In SQL I often use CASE statements nested in a summary function. This type of syntax works nicely to calculate all sort of ratios between sums/counts of certain rows vs sum/counts of other rows in a table.

```
select a, b,
sum(case when d='xyz' then 1 else 0 end)/
count(distinct case when f='abc' then a end) as new_field
from table
group by a, b
```

How can you do that type of thing in Pandas?

Comment: The SQL isn't that useful. Provide example data frames of what you're starting with and the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function to a `groupby` object using `apply`:

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3], 'B':list('abcceegh'),'C':list('kmopmmmn'),'D':list('tauaaasf')})


def f(x):
    return x[x['C'] == 'm']['A'].sum()/ x[x['D'] == 'a']['A'].count()

df.groupby(['B']).apply(f)
```

returns:

```
B
a    0
b    1
c    0
e    2
g    0
h    0
```

dtype: int64